# Build script to Makefile

Tags: makefile

I struggle to write Makefiles and I'm [building up some examples](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/makefile-tracking-yyyy-mm-directories/7384#7384) to learn from. I want to use Makefiles since it makes builds concurrent, projects more uniform and easier to manage.

Do you have any resources to share?

For example I am struggling to think how to turn this simple build script into a Makefile, so that index.html is only built when its index.src.html is modified.

```
for i in */index.src.html
do
    anolis --max-depth=3 $i $(dirname $i)/index.html
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a pattern rule. From [the GNU Makefile manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions):

> Thus, a pattern rule ‘%.o : %.c’ says how to make any file stem.o from another file stem.c.

So, something like

```
INFILES = $(shell find . -name index.src.html)
OUTFILES = $(addsuffix .html, $(basename $(basename $(INFILES))))

default: $(OUTFILES)

%.html : %.src.html
    anolis --max-depth=3 $< $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTFILES)
```

The trick then becomes building up `INFILES` in a reliable and safe way.

Comment: s,%.src,%.src.html, otherwise fantastic stuff! Works great :)

Comment: Just a stylistic point: you may also use a substitution reference to generate `OUTFILES`: `OUTFILES = $(INFILES:.src.html=.html)`. This makes it just a little bit more clear what's happening.