# Expanding dependency's dirname for Makefile wildcard

Tags: makefile

Following on from [Build script to Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709503/build-script-to-makefile), which lives in this [upstream location](http://tests.wacapps.net/index.cgi?p=wacspecs;a=blob;f=Makefile). I want to include the Javascript examples that are included into this generated HTML document as dependencies.

```
INFILES = $(shell find . -name "index.src.html")
OUTFILES = $(INFILES:.src.html=.html)
TEMP:= $(shell mktemp -u /tmp/specs.XXXXXX)

all: $(OUTFILES)

# Problem line:
%.html: %.src.html $(wildcard contacts/*js)
    @echo Dependencies: $^
    cd $(@D) && m4 -PEIinc index.src.html > $(TEMP)
    anolis --max-depth=3 $(TEMP) $@
    rm -f $(TEMP)

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTFILES)

PHONY: all clean
```

I want `$(wildcard contacts/*js)` to be `$(wildcard $(@D)/*js)` or `$(wildcard $(dirname %)/*js)`, but nothing I've tried works. There must be some sort of keyword to get the parent directory of the target or dependency so I can reference the javascript dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, using `$(@D)` and other [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) inside list of prerequisites can only be achieved using [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) feature of GNU Make.

Thus, your problem probably can be solved as follows:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.html: %.src.html $$(wildcard $$(@D)/*js)
```

However, I'm not sure whether it will work with pattern rules.

Comment: Eclipse plug-in development (just for fun), are you crazy? :P

Comment: @hendry, yeah, sometimes it gives loooots of fun! :-)